# pyqtgraph get the PlotItem under mouse

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I recently started using PyQt5 and pyqtgraph instead of Matplotlib and tkinter because of it's plotting "speed" (pyqtgraph). I am really trying to get to know this library. I have a simple question. No matter the time i spent on searching the internet, i could't find an answer... How can i get the PlotItem that is under my mouse. I have a `GraphicsLayoutWidget` and three PlotItem in it. I want to know every time  which of these PlotItems is under my cursor. I want to know this information because i want to change the x-axis limits only on the PlotItem, that my cursor is above. When i say PlotItem i mean the equivalent Matplotlib axes (i have this in my mind). The equivalent Matplotlib command is `event.inaxes()`. I hope my problem is understood. Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you want to recognize what item is when it is clicked? o just with the hover?

Comment: Well i would prefer "hover" because I am using pyqt5 keypressevent and when I press a keyboard key I want the axis limits to change on the plotitem under the cursor.